# modifying custom type Rcpp::List objects in place

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am struggling to figure out how to modify custom type list elements in an Rcpp::List; below is some code to illustrate my problem (using Rcpp modules).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

class Base {

public:

    Rcpp::NumericVector data;

    Base() {
        this->data = Rcpp::NumericVector();
    }

    void append(double x) {
        data.push_back(x);
    }

};
RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Base)


class Container {

public:

    Rcpp::List objects;

    Container(Rcpp::List objects) {
        this->objects = objects;
    }

    void append(double x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) {
            // cannot modify in-place because objects[i] is a temporary!
            const Base *obj = objects[i];
            // try to outsmart the compiler by copying to non const - lvalue hell!
            Base *ptr = obj;
            ptr->append(x);
        }
    }

    Base* at(int i) {
        void *ptr = objects[i];
        return (Base*) ptr;
    }

};
RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Container)
```

The problem is that I need to call the method `Base::append` and thus need to get a non-const pointer to the i-th list element. Since `objects[i]` is a temporary object, I cannot define a non-const pointer though. Here I tried copying the const pointer, but the compiler complains about not being able to initialize the non-const pointer with a const lvalue (I guess that means it realized I was trying to outsmart it).

Do I need to use another (typed) collection instead of Rcpp::List or how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how R objects work (Rcpp being a wrapper). The key is

1. R objects are all pointers (SEXP being a pointer to SEXPREC)
2. When you `push_back` to a vector you are potentially changing the underlying pointer.

Therefore your NumericVectors are not guaranteed to refer to the same object after `push_back`.

One option is to build your `Base` class using references. Here's an example.

```
sourceCpp("mycontainer.cpp")
x <- as.list(1:5)
mc <- new(Container, x)
mc$append(6)
print(x)
[[1]]
[1] 1 6

[[2]]
[1] 2 6

[[3]]
[1] 3 6
...
```

Rcpp code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

class Base {
public:
  Rcpp::NumericVector & data;
  Base(Rcpp::NumericVector & x) : data(x) {}
  void append(double x) {
    data.push_back(x);
  }
};
RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Base)
  
  
class Container {
  
public:
  Rcpp::List objects;
  Container(Rcpp::List objects) {
    this->objects = objects;
  }
  void append(double x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) {
      Rcpp::NumericVector objvec = objects[i];
      Base obj( objvec );
      obj.append(x);
      objects[i] = objvec;
    }
  }
  Rcpp::List output() {
    return objects;
  }
};
RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Container)

RCPP_MODULE(Container){
  using namespace Rcpp;
  class_<Container>("Container")
  .constructor< List >()
  .method( "append", &Container::append )
  .method( "output", &Container::output )
  ;
}
```

Edit: You can see how the pointer (SEXP) changes on push_back.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test() {
  IntegerVector x(0);
  std::cout << (void*) x.get__() << std::endl;
  x[0] = 50;
  std::cout << (void*) x.get__() << std::endl; // no change
  x.push_back(1);
  std::cout << (void*) x.get__() << std::endl; // address change
}
```

Comment: thanks, just figured it out as well x) So, the key is to have a container class with a container on the C++ side. I can refer to that from an R session via the exposed pointer and pass it to other exposed classes/functions who then can access the memory directly. If my container is an R list directly, the objects are copied / non referentiable.

Comment: Can you expand on _When you push_back to a vector you are potentially changing the underlying pointer._ ?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel See the edit at the bottom. In Jack's case it causes the NumericVector stored in his `Base` class to no longer point to the same data.

Comment: That's a different issue (copy-on-write) and you really shouldn't used `push_back()` on these vectors as the documentation says in a few places.  To me that is a bit different from your statement implying 'objects change when injected into a container' (which was how I read it in the context of the question).  Anyway, thanks for clarifying; I think your edit shows a, shall we say, 'uncommon' usage pattern. But hey C and C++ let you shoot yourself in the foot in many ways.

Comment: "But hey C and C++ let you shoot yourself in the foot in many ways". My feet have many holes!

Comment: To wit, if you do (in R) `x <- numeric(0); .Internal(inspect(x))` followed by `x[1] <- 2; .Internal(inspect(x))` it also shows that the object and its address changes.  That's just R for you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really have time to work through your problem but from a first glance it appears to be related to the `objects` instance being *local* to your object which runs into issue that have more to do with C++ lifetime scope than with Rcpp interfaces.

When I wanted or needed more permanent "collections" of things, I usually stripped the problem away by ensuring the "collector", here your `objects` was *global* and lasted.  One (very basic) solution for that is a static pointer which a few helper functions to a) initialize, b) add an object, c) fetch an object (by key or position) and of course d) unwind / cleanup at end.  It is still a little tricky because you want to make sure there aren't multiple copies of your collector (the static part helps).

Comment: Thanks for giving it a look anyhow, I think I see what you meen. Sounds awefully fragile/complex, probs beyond my reach.

Comment: It really isn't. I often wrap it into a simple class holding such a pointer. You could then tailor the four functions I sketched via Rcpp Modules.  Give it some thought over the next few days, do some paper sketches.  It's not hard but your current approach is, IIUIC, fundamentally limited and cannot do what you want it to do.